# How can I include information from multiple rows into one row based on an identifier in R?

Tags: r

In R, I would like to make my data set usable for research by including the information on multiple rows with the same identifier into one row. My data set has the structure that every `id` is unique, but there are multiple rows containing information for this `id`. Since there is already some information stored in every row with value `7` as `number`, I would like to keep these rows and include the rest of the information from the other rows.

My data set has the following structure:

```
id    number  var1  var2  var3  var4 var5

id01  3       a     NULL  6     4    5
id01  3       a     3     NULL  9    8
id02  2       b     NULL  22    4    NULL
id02  4       b     NULL  NULL  7    4
id02  7       b     NULL  NULL  9    8
id02  7       b     6     NULL  8    6
id03  2       c     NULL  33    4    1
id03  6       c     NULL  NULL  9    3
id03  7       c     9     NULL  7    9
id04  2       d     NULL  98    9    2
id04  3       d     NULL  NULL  4    NULL
id04  4       d     NULL  NULL  7    NULL
id04  7       d     7     NULL  8    2
```

And this is my desired output:

```
id      var1  var2  var3  var4     var5

id01    a     3     6     4;9      NA
id02    b     6     22    4;7;8;9  8;6
id03    c     9     33    4;7;9    9
id04    d     7     98    4;7;8;9  2
```

As you can see, there are multiple cases

- In **var1**, all column values for the rows corresponding to an id
  are equal to the value which should be included in the desired
  dataset. Since it is desired to keep the row with number 7, I think we don't need to do anything to keep this value in the desired output.
- In **var2** and **var3**  all column values are equal to NULL, except for one
  row which has a value (in different places for var2 and var3). The value should be included in the desired dataset
- In **var4** all column values should be included in the desired
  dataset in one string, separated by a semi colon (the specific
  seperation character doesn't matter though)
- In **var5** the row value with `7` under `number` should stay in the data set. For example, for `id=03`, the value in this row for `var5` should come in the new data set (9). If there are no matches with `7` under `number`, then a NA should be included. If there are multiple matches, then these should be printed in a string, separated by (for example) a semi colon.

I would like to determine the behavior per column and not for the whole data set. In R, how should I approach this?

Comment: What does `NULL` mean in your data? Missing values or literal strings?

Comment: They can be treated as missing values, since they contain no information, but I think they are literal strings (?) Since R used NA for missing values (corrent me if I'm wrong)

Comment: You can use `read.table(..., na.strings = "NULL")` to read the file and all `NULL` will be converted to `NA` in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can summarise each column by group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(var1 = first(var1),
            var2 = if(all(is.na(var2))) NA else na.omit(var2),
            var3 = if(all(is.na(var3))) NA else na.omit(var3),
            var4 = toString(sort(var4)),
            var5 = na_if(toString(var5[number == 7]), ""),
            number = 7)

# # A tibble: 4 x 7
#   id    var1   var2  var3 var4       var5  number
#   <fct> <fct> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 id01  a         3     6 4, 9       NA         7
# 2 id02  b         6    22 4, 7, 8, 9 8, 6       7
# 3 id03  c         9    33 4, 7, 9    9          7
# 4 id04  d         7    98 4, 7, 8, 9 2          7
```

***Note:*** `number` must be set after `var5`. If you set `number = 7` before `var5`, then values in `number` will all be redefined as 7 so that `var5 = var5[number == 7]` doesn't work.

---

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("id01", "id02", "id03", "id04"
), class = "factor"), number = c(2L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 
6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L), var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"
), class = "factor"), var2 = c(NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 
9L, NA, NA, NA, 7L), var3 = c(6L, NA, 22L, NA, NA, NA, 33L, NA, 
NA, 98L, NA, NA, NA), var4 = c(4L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 
7L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 8L), var5 = c(5L, 8L, NA, 4L, 8L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 
9L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm very close. However, I've added a last scenario (see my original question) which is described as var5. How would I approach this in your dplyr solution?

Comment: Thanks, in my data set, there are also cases with no matches or multiple matches to the var5[number == 7] addition. Therefore, I get the error ''Column `var5` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0'' (or not 2). I've updated my start post. How to approach this?

Comment: @Silhouettes you can use `toString()` to paste multiple matches together and `na_if()` to convert no match into `NA`. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, your Note was indeed necessary. If the columns are swapped it doesn't work, so this did the trick perfectly

Answer (score 0):

in Base-R

If `NULL` in your data is a string. You'll want to change `mydata` to whatever you've named your data.

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
    lapply(split(mydata, mydata$id), apply, 2, function(x) paste(unique(x[x!="NULL"]),collapse=';') )
))
```

output:

```
       id  number var1 var2 var3    var4
id01 id01     2;7    a    3    6     4;9
id02 id02 2;4;5;7    b    6   22 4;7;9;8
id03 id03   2;6;7    c    9   33   4;9;7
id04 id04 2;3;4;7    d    7   98 9;4;7;8
```

Data:

```
mydata <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("id01", "id02", "id03", "id04"
), class = "factor"), number = c(2L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 
6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L), var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"
), class = "factor"), var2 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("3", "6", "7", "9", 
"NULL"), class = "factor"), var3 = structure(c(3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("22", "33", "6", 
"98", "NULL"), class = "factor"), var4 = c(4L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 
8L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Comment: Thanks, but your line of code applies to the whole data set. Is there a way to remove all rows from the data set but the rows with "7" under number, and then include all information as you did? I would like to determine the behavior per column and not for the whole data set

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your desired output then. If we look at the subset `mydata[mydata$number==7,]` then you lose all the extra information? Do you just want the number 7 to be displayed? Seems a touch meaningless. But if you could do this with `output$number <- 7`

Comment: or if you keep the output as is, you could call `output[grep("4",output$number),]` for instance to get only the rows in which number `4` appear.